# How to connect two databases to hibernate eclipse web project?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

MY project is java ee web application I used hibernate for database purposes. I connect one data base to this application now I need to connect another mysql database to this project how can I do this is it possible? can you give me proper link or solution thanx in advanced

I used this 1st answer thanx lot for that but it gives this exception can you please help me to solve this 
{16:02:39,552  WARN SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9001/openreports
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1174)
    at org.efs.openreports.actions.admin.ServerDataAction.(ServerDataAction.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:71)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowire(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:253)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:143)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:113)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:365)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.access$000(DefaultActionInvocation.java:38)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$1.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:83)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.(DefaultActionInvocation.java:74)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:494)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16:02:39,610  WARN SessionFactoryObjectFactory - InitialContext did not implement EventContext                                                                                  this is my error msg what is reson for this can you please help me..........}

Answer (score 2):

To connect with two database you need two `SessionFactory`

**Hints**:

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory1 = new  Configuration().configure("config1.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
 SessionFactory sessionFactory2 = new Configuration().configure("config2.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();


void yourMethod() {
        try {
            session = sessionFactory1.openSession();
            // here play with session of sessionFactory1
            session.close();

            session = sessionFactory2.openSession();
           // here play with session of sessionFactory2
            session.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("It works");
        }
    }
```

If you are using spring see [load two database](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/LoadTwoDataSources.htm)

Comment: thanx I used this but have exception [wrong worning
15:51:24,978  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
15:51:24,978 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - No suitable driver found for hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9001/openreports
15:51:24,995  WARN SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection metadata
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9001/openreports
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)] can I  solve this

Comment: @user1770534, it seems you are not using proper driver. check your driver for hsql is it in your class path?.

Comment: THIS IS MY DATABASE PATH: <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">misd</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://16.2.2.135:3306/pbdsp</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">misd</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
  <mapping resource="org/efs/openreports/objects/ToremoveObject.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>

Comment: your question is closed, open another thread with all the code what you tried and what you want.

Comment: I solve database connection problem it's give error for I mis the ":"jdbc:mysql://10.1.2.130/pbdsp this but it's give exception for WARN SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Could not bind factory to JNDI
javax.naming.NamingException: Name is not valid so, remove factory name also but it not solve can you help me please

Comment: Is your code working for single database?

Comment: yes it's woking single databse

Comment: I have problem for this mysql database how can i solve this

Comment: Is your code is working for only mysql? I mean if you are using single database with mysql is it working?

Comment: i have hsql data base  I connected it using hibernate so, it's properly working but i want to connect my sql database to my project so I used your early mention method but it's not working it gives this exception."WARN SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Could not bind factory to JNDI
javax.naming.NamingException: Name is not valid"